# Is there DDL Auditing in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, auditing, ddl-trigger

And if not, is there a way to tell when a trigger was disabled/enabled?

**FOLLOWUP:**

It's a rather interesting diagnostic case. I was only involved from the periphery, and the guy doing the diagnostics isn't a database guy.

Anyways, he had a trigger that would move data from one table to another. He did a comparison and not all the data had made it to the second table. I said, I'm a critic of SQL Server but I trust that their triggers fire in the same transaction. He said but some of the data made it... if it was just disabled, nothing should make it. True. So I said maybe someone is enabling and disabling the triggers. Hence the question.

But what really happened is someone permanently disabled the trigger and copied the code into a sproc that was set to run at a certain time.

The correct forensic test would have been to look at the dependencies of the second table, see what else was using it. That would show the tumor sproc... (I've been watching lots of [House](http://www.fox.com/house/) reruns, can ya tell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem looks quite similar to the one that Randy Volters wrote about in Simple-Talk

http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/dml-trigger-status-alerts/

I suspect it will help

Comment: MSSS says they're improving, and I've believed them up until now...>>> But if the DISABLE TRIGGER, ENABLE TRIGGER, or the GUI of the Management Studio, were used to change a trigger’s status, the information would not be collected. <<< What's the point of DDL auditing if you don't audit ALL DDL?

Answer (score 1):

No auditing, though there is a company called Lumigent that offers a product "Audit DB" which will do DDL auditing (among other things) for SQL Server.

You can look in the sysobjects table for the crdate which will tell you when the object was created.

Comment: And CRdate will tell me the time the status was changed from enabled to disabled or the reverse?